installing R package encounter warning message "problem copying: Permission denied" when using R Interactive in VScode
I want to run R command via VScode R interactive terminal. However, when I install the package "languageserver", everything is ok except the warning message" problem copying C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\languageserver\libs\x64\languageserver.dll to C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\languageserver\libs\x64\languageserver.dll: Permission denied

How can I copy the "languagerserver.dll" to that path? Is there any problem if I don't copy it to the path?
My R version and system environment is :

